# TFS 2015. the $(var.SourceLocation) variable is not available at gated-check in

Tags: azure-devops, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

We are migrating from old `XAML` build definition to new TFS 2015 build. In old we have gated-check in that is working fine. In new one we have such option on "Triggers" tab. However I want use commit ID that trigger build.
The variable `$(Build.SourceVersion)` is responsible for this, but for gated-check in it is not being set.
It looks right, because commit was not accepted by TFS yet.

The question is how to grab this commit ID either during gated-check in or following CI ?

Should I create just another build for gated check-in that just compile our solution and only if succeeded will trigger CI ?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the commit ID? I don't understand what the problem is. You shouldn't need the commit ID unless you're trying to do something like pass it to a script.

Comment: I need commit id to generate special folder name and put on server. like "dev_build_c6445_20170120.1".

Comment: @Alezis, Do you mean gated check-in trigger or CI trigger? Git team project doesn't support gated check-in trigger in TFS 2015.Or you want to say changeset ID instead of commit ID?

Comment: My goal to replicate old XAML builds. We would like have just gated check-in. In addition we need to inject exact changeset  id into drop folder on a server. this changeset can help us find correct sources the build was createdfrom.we use TFS as source control version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far, I end up with not clean workaround, but it were accepted by our management. 
I created two build definitions: one for gated-check in, one for CI.
Once someone checked in something gated check-in fires. If it completed successfully, CI build would be triggered. Please note corresponding checkbox on UI:

[image: gated]
[image: CI]

This is not so clean solution, but it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to get the changeset id that hasn't checked in during gated check-in. Please check the screenshot below, checking in gated changes is in the very last step in the build process, which can't be controlled. After the build completes, the variable `$(Build.SourceVersion)` will update automatically. So we are not able to get the changeset id that hasn't checked in until the build completes.

[image]

You would need to use [TFS REST API to get the build](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/builds#get-a-build) that has completed, then fetch the  "sourceVersion":

```
GET http://{instance}/DefaultCollection/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}?api-version={version}
```