# TFS 2015 build vNext update file version with commit id

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

Do you know how inject commit id into file version, so every assembly would heve version like `2.0.6565.0` where 6565 is related to `C6565`commit ID in TFS ?

It looks some power shell script is needed.

Comment: Is this question similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41763224/tfs-2015-the-var-sourcelocation-variable-is-not-available-at-gated-check-in?

Comment: @Cece - MSFT, This question about updating dll with commit/changeset id. Why you down-voted ? Could you explain, what is wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I created my own PS script based on [this post](https://intovsts.net/2015/08/24/tfs-build-2015-and-versioning/).
The idea update version in all files with assembly info

```
$CommitId = ([string]$env:BUILD_SOURCEVERSION) -replace "[^0-9]+", ""
$AllVersionFiles = Get-ChildItem $SourceDir AssemblyInfo.cs -recurse
$regexToFindVersion = "Version\(""([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+).+"""

foreach ($file in $AllVersionFiles) 
{
    Write-Host "Processing " $file.FullName

    (Get-Content $file.FullName) |
    %{$_ -replace $regexToFindVersion, ('Version("$1.$2.0.' + $CommitId + '"') } |
    Set-Content $file.FullName -Force
}
```

Full script can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/Alezis/6e5cf5b167c5caf42feac6032af0462b).

The script must be placed before building project:
[image: BuildSteps]

Comment: Is this script can be modified to change only product version instead of file and product version?

Comment: What do you mean by "product version" ? This script can update assembly version and file version of assembly. It hits 'AssemblyVersion' and  'AssemblyFileVersion' attributes. You can change logic to whatever you want by changing regex.  If you need only file version, then use something like "FileVersion\(""([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+).+"""

Answer (score 0):

If your question is similar to your another post [TFS 2015. the $(var.SourceLocation) variable is not available at gated-check in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41763224/tfs-2015-the-var-sourcelocation-variable-is-not-available-at-gated-check-in), that want to get the changeset id that hasn't checked in during gated check-in, then it's impossible in a single build.

If you don't use gated check in, then you can use `$Env:BUILD_SOURCEVERSION` in a powershell script to set the AssemblyVersion. Here is already a script at the website below, you can refer to it:

https://github.com/wulfland/ScriptRepository/blob/master/TFSBuild/TFSBuild/AssemblyVersion/Set-AssemblyVersion/Set-AssemblyVersion.ps1

Comment: Again, this is different question. Second part of your post looks interesting.